# rdoc generated documents publically accessible

Tags: security, rdoc

I have make rdoc to generate the documentation of my project but now i would like to make them accessible from application so allowed (logged in users) can access/view them from my site.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If my answer was sufficient for you, I'd appreciate an acceptance. If not, then could you please post your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, what type of application are you running? If it's something like MVC (or has a routing layer) you could probably specify some type of hook or serve them from a controller such that the path `doc/<rdoc-files>` was handled by a controller that would perform user-auth and then serve whatever static file the user is requesting.

You could also put everything into an IFrame that takes up the whole window (and really shouldn't be visible) and you could serve the IFrame server-side and include your authentication there.

There are really many ways in which you could prevent un-authorized users from accessing your documentation. It really just depends on what you are comfortable with.